# Alien: .rpm -> .deb | Compability / Built per system?

Tags: debian, rpm, repository

At the moment I'm playing a bit with alien (for OpenVZ packages on Debian) and was wondering myself about one question for which I was not able to find an answer anywhere.
Therefor I thought it might be smart to ask here :)

**The question is...**
If I convert a .rpm to .deb on a system, how compatible is this .deb package?

**What do I mean?**
Will the .deb be working on other systems as well or is it per-system, e.g. that on every system the .deb package will be little different?

That i386 and x86_64 are different is clear, so this doesn't need to be answered :)

Examples that would be nice to know are for example:

.deb built on Debian 6 64-bit -> Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit (compatible?)
.deb built on Debian 6 64-bit -> Debian 5 64-bit (compatible?)
etc.

Thanks anyone reading this / helping me!

Regards,
Michel

Comment: OK it seems that they are NOT built per system (but per arch, which is clear).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that `alien` does is take the contents of the RPM and rearrange their packaging to turn them into a `.deb` archive (along with trying to synthesize proper package metadata based on the metadata in the RPM).  It doesn't change anything at all about the binaries; it just copies them from the RPM.

Therefore, the binaries installed as part of the `.deb` package will be just as portable as the binaries in the original RPM.  If those binaries will run on the target system, they'll still run when installed via the `.deb`.